# Registrando valor de uma variavel numa tabela

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, query, ado.net

Estou tentando salvar os dados de 2 variáveis numa tabela, mas quando vou olha a tabela no banco é registrado os valores como 0.

```
       public void inserir(List<Conta>list)
    {
        List<Conta> lista = new List<Conta>();

        lista = list;

        try
        {
            MySqlConnection onclick = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; port=3306; User Id=root; database = 2.0 banco; password =");
            onclick.Open();



            MySqlCommand onCmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO CONTA(nome, cpf) VALUES (nome = @nome, cpf = @cpf)", onclick);


            onCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome",lista[lista.Count-1].GetNome()); 
            onCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", lista[lista.Count - 1].GetCpf());               
            onCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Cadastrado com sucesso: " + lista[lista.Count - 1].GetCpf());
        }
        catch(Exception erro)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Erro ao cadastrar: " + erro);

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sintaxe usada é um misto de inserção e atualização, o que está errado, o correto é:

```
"INSERT INTO CONTA(nome, cpf) VALUES (@nome, @cpf)"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/InsertVar.cs).

Tem coisas bem esquisitas, não recomendadas no código ou com potencial para erro, então pode ter mais alguma coisa. E você não salva variáveis no banco de dados, salva valores, eles podem estar originalmente armazenados na variável.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado.